# Распарсить json в php

Tags: php, json

подчскажите, что-то не додумываю как распарсить такой массив

```
{"1":{"hdate":"1","duedate":"1","rub":"3","eur":"1","debit":"2","credit":"3","balanse":"3"},
```

Comment: `json_decode()` пробовали?

Comment: Что именно не получается? Для работы с json в php есть json_decode() и json_encode() это все, что нужно знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '{"1":{"hdate":"1","duedate":"1","rub":"3","eur":"1","debit":"2","credit":"3","balanse":"3"}}';
$jdecode = json_decode($str);
var_dump($jdecode);
```

Результат:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public '1' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'hdate' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'duedate' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'rub' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'eur' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'debit' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'credit' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'balanse' => string '3' (length=1)
```